# r system function to cd into a folder name with space

Tags: r, linux, escaping, system, cd

I trying to `cd` into this folder in my linux system from R.

/projects/Temp/Global Warming

I use the `system` function like this below

```
system("cd /projects/Temp/Global Warming; ls")
```

and this is not working.

If I try one level up, `system("cd /projects/Temp; ls")` everything works fine without any problems, but when it try to cd into the folder `Global Warming` the space is folder name is creating some problems. Any advise on how to fix this issue is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is this just a minimal example of something you're trying to do or is there a reason you don't want to use `dir` or `list.files` to get the contents of a system folder?

Comment: @Dason, my objective is something other than just list files :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an R issue but more of a general command line issue. For `cd` you need to quote the path if it contains spaces.

`'cd "/projects/Temp/Global Warming"; ls'` should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to enter a directory and list it's contents, you could change your working directory to the folder and list its contents:

```
setwd("path/to/folder with space")
list.files()
```

or:

```
list.files("path/to/folder with space")
```

to just list the files in the directory, regardless of current directory or working directory.

Comment: You don't need to escape whitespace for character vector paths in R, so `list.files("path/to/folder with space")`  will also work. His problem was that he passes the command on to the bash command `cd`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; I updated my answer. I avoid spaces in folder/file names, so I've never actually had to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

In R, replacing a space in a file path with four consecutive backslashes followed by a space (i.e., "\\\\ ") solves the issue.

I recommending doing this dynamically using gsub()

Here is the full solution:

```
myPath <- "/projects/Temp/Global Warming"
system(paste0("cd ", gsub(" ","\\\\ ",myPath), " && ls"))
```

Note: In linux, you can use && if you actually want to list files in the directory of interest.